# In VSCode snippets, how can I capitalize the value of another user-defined variable?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm in VSCode trying to make snippets and get my head around some of the new regex replacement syntax.

What I want to do is populate parts of my template based on the filename. I can strip the unwanted extensions okay, but I can't capitalize the same value in the next variable.

I have these two lines:

`"@Controller('/${1:${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)\\.controller/$1/}}')",
"export class ${1/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}Controller {",`

The first strips filename and captures the value as $1 for the template.
In the second line, I'm trying to use the value from $1 and run it through the capitalize filter.

Nothing I've tried works, although bashing my head against the keyboard feels kind of nice.

Has anyone cracked this nut?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works at least as of v1.25:

```
"@Controller('/${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)\\.controller/$1/}')",
"export class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)$/${1:/capitalize}/}Controller {",
```

yields:

```
@Controller('/myGlobalSnippets')
export class MyGlobalSnippetsController {
```