# Transform and regex in Code Snippets in VSCode - Docs

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I need list of transormations, like downcase, upcase, capitalize.
Where is the list of such? Good documentation.

Answer (score 7):

The official documentation is [snippets grammar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar).  It shows the transforms but only provides one example.  The built-in transforms are

```
/upcase or /downcase or /capitalize or /pascalcase
```

`/pascalcase` was added by [a commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/0604b4f7c48af64fc22644ae02d4b367848c0a3f) on October 2, 2018 but hasn't made it into the documentation (as of June, 2019).  It works to do this:

`some-file-name.js => SomeFileName`  // or another separator like `_` or any `[^a-z]/i` character.

Since the capability of snippet transforms has recently been enhanced, see [placeholder transforms, v1.25 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_snippet-placeholder-transformations) (with another example)  there should be more examples arriving on SO soon.

For examples, see [capitalized a snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47235159/in-vscode-snippets-how-can-i-capitalize-the-value-of-another-user-defined-varia/51228027#51228027) and

[transform foo_bar to FooBar, camelCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104851/snippet-regex-match-arbitrary-number-of-groups-and-transform-to-camelcase/51228186#51228186) and

[capitalize classNames of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250474/how-to-generate-smarter-complex-snippets-in-visual-studio-visual-studio-code/51228442#51228442) and
[lowercase a component name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487060/visual-studio-code-replace-char-case-while-typing-in-snippet).