# VS Code Snippet | Placeholder + Transform

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

### Goal

I can't find a way to create the following snippet :

```
[
    "${1:SECTION NAME/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}",
    "====================================\n$0"
]
```

I want the following outcome :

```
<selection>SECTION NAME</selection>
====================================
```

I then enter: "i am hopeless". [TAB]

```
I AM HOPELESS
====================================
<selection />
```

---

### Almost there!!

The closest I got is this :

```
[
    "${1/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/} ${1:SECTION NAME}",
    "====================================\n$0"
]
```

But I get a duplicate.

Comment: Just use : "${1/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}",   It isn't clear, do you want the <selection></selection> tags as well?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding! I want a placeholder at `$1` (before editing it). The `selection` tag is meant to simulate the **step-by-step** snippet mechanism.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transform and regex in Code Snippets in VSCode - Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227382/transform-and-regex-in-code-snippets-in-vscode-docs)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just to save some frustration, placeholder transforms do **not** work on **default or choice** syntaxes.  As in:

```
"${1:foo/(.*)/$1:/upcase}/}"
"${2:|foo,bar|/(.*)/{1:/upcase}/}",
```

They do work when there is no default or choice value.  So the following works:

```
 "${3/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}",
```

Also, you can use a default variable if it is not transformed at the inital tabstop but is later transformed on a subsequent usage.  So the following works:

```
  "${4:SECTION NAME}",      
  "${4/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}",
```

or the reverse also works:

```
  "${3/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}",
  "${3:SECTION NAME}",
```

So you can provide a default but it cannot be transformed until another reference to that same tabstop.

See the discussion [vscode issues: placeholder transforms](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/51621).  No word if work on supporting transforms of default/choice variables is being worked on.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! `Just to save some frustration...` > Yes, I think I came across this situation once, but I felt like maybe I misunderstood something back then. Thanks for the link!

Comment: When I tried the hack with `${4:SECTION NAME}` or `${3:SECTION NAME}`, one of those default texts didn't transform to uppercase. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am trying to achieve something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869050/how-to-fill-line-to-certain-length-using-regex-replace

Comment: Thank you so very much. I was struggling with this a lot and your example for how it works with a default variable just saved my day.