# How to pad out line to certain length using regex replace and snippets

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

`// My Section -----------------------------------------------------------------`

The above is the desired result.

---

Imagine this scenario

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// firebase

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// utils
```

It is possible to trim lines to a certain length using for example this regex `/(^.{20}).*$/$1/`, which will give

```
// -----------------
// firebase

// -----------------
// utils
```

> But what if I want to fill the other lines instead up to the set
>   length like this in one run? Is that possible?
>
> - one regex for only the right fill, not the trim
>
> ```
> // -----------------
> // firebase --------
>
> // -----------------
> // utils -----------
> ```

Ages ago, I was doing some regex ninja challenges and we were supposed to do math, so.... regex is magical.

---

What I am ultimately trying to achieve is a VSCode snippet that allows me to write: `My Section --`
then trigger a snippet that transforms the inserted text into an 80 character wide comment containing

```
// My Section -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Are you looking for a JavaScript code with regex or vscode functionality with regex?

Comment: I dont know. but if you made it. share it with me please. I want such thing as well

Comment: Ultimately I want that VSCode snippet, but I want to know an alternative to `/(^.{20}).*$/$1/` that inserts characters at the end of the line up to a desired length. Then I will apply this transformation to a VSCode snippet.

Comment: Regex is a way to find specific patterns, you can not replace characters only by use of regex.

Comment: @ArashKhajelou I should have been more specific that I am using regex replace pattern that uses regex to match the source.

Comment: something like sed command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you can do what you want in one step, without running some code.  But you can do it with a macro so you can have multiple steps fired at once.  In this example I am using the macro extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), but there are other macro extensions out there.

In your settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

 {
   "command": "multiCommand.commentSection",
   // "interval": 750,  // you don't need this, just for illustration

   "sequence": [  
     "cursorEnd",            
     {
       "command": "type",  // add 75 -'s'
       "args": {
         "text": " ---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
       }
     },

     "editor.action.addCommentLine",

     // select this wrapped line so the next snippet can use TM_SELECTED_TEXT
     "cursorHomeSelect",
     "cursorHomeSelect",

     {
       "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",  // trim to first 80 characters
       "args": {
         "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.{80}).*/$1/g}",
       }
     }
   ]
 }
],
```

And then whatever keybinding you choose in keybindings.json

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+-",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.commentSection" }
},
```

The basic idea is to add too many hyphens - say 75 - and then select the entire wrapped line and keep only the first 80 characters, thus trimming the trailing hyphens to fill out to 80 total characters on the line.

It works on blank lines too as the end of the demo demonstrates.

[image: demo of padding a line with characters to a certain length]

Comment: Amazing solution. Now it would be great if it was possible to run macros by text triggers (as insertSnippet).

Comment: I see I forgot the make  it into a `comment` part of your question - so I added that with a new demo - in the hopes of capturing that elusive accepted answer ;>}  You can't trigger a macro with a snippet prefix but there isn't much difference.  Instead of typing some snippet prefix like `-- [tab]` you type the macro keybinding, which could be two keys if you wish.

Comment: You are right, but as a side note: the text tirggers are little more convenient: 1) a list of all matching snippets appears and you can select from them, also you get intellisense when you start typing. You always invoke with the same key [tab], 2) you don't have to remember weird key combos or train your muscle memory. Pressing multiple keys is always harder than typing. Thanks anyway, this is a great solution which I will use (I have already trained my muscle memory :) )

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer which is very different than my previous macro extension answer.

I made an extension, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), which does this rather easily because you can perform a javascript operation, like math, right in a find/replace.

Using this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+r",                      // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
       
    "find": "(${TM_CURRENT_LINE})",
    
    "replace": "${LINE_COMMENT} $${ return '$1 '.padEnd(79 - '${LINE_COMMENT}'.length, '-') }$$",

    "isRegex": true,
    "restrictFind": "line"    // can have multiple lines with a cursor
}
```

Alternatively, you can put this (in a slightly different form) into your `settings.json` from which a command will be created - and so accessible from the Command Palette and more easily synced between set-ups.

[image: padEnd to 80 with Find and Transform extension]

---

`"replace": "${LINE_COMMENT} $${ return '$1 '.padEnd(79 - '${LINE_COMMENT}'.length, '-') }$$",`

Replace with a line comment for the current editor language. Add to that a javascript operation denoted by `$${...}$$` to make parsing easier.

`return '$1 '.padEnd(79 - '${LINE_COMMENT}'.length, '-')` return capture group 1 (followed by one space) and padded out to 80 total characters (must account for the space after the line comment characters `//` ).  Subtracting the length of the line comment characters which can vary by language.

Note that the items which represent strings, like `$1`  and  `${LINE_COMMENT}` are denoted as strings by single quotes (you could also use backticks).  Otherwise javascript will interpret them as unknown variable names.

If you didn't care about working with different style and length line comments you could use the simpler:

`"replace": "// $${ return '$1'.padEnd(79, '-') }$$",`

Comment: This is interesting, I was looking at this QA just yesterday and I wanted to add a comment that I am still using your script. I shall try your new solution quickly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use callback function of replace and based on length you can replace values

```js
let str = `// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// firebase

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// utils`

let final = str.replace(/^.*$/gm, (match)=>{
  return match.length === 0 ? match : match.length > 20 ? match.substr(0,20) : match + `-`.repeat(20-match.length)
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: I can't run a javascript code, it has to be done using the regex engine.