# How to create a comment block of //'s around text of different lengths

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm curious, if there's a way to create these blocks automatically around a text? Currently working in VS / VSCode projects.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////// Demo Text /////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Due to varying text length, this can be really annoying.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at snippets. Both VS and VSC include support for custom snippets.

Comment: if you have no taste there is always [Banner Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lunarlimbo.banner-comments-plus)

Comment: But those hurts my eyes and soul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a vscode solution.  You will need some macro extension to run several commands in a row.  Here I am using multi-command for example.  See https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command

settings.json:

```
{
  "command": "multiCommand.createTextBlock2",
  // "interval": 350,
  "sequence": [

    "cursorEnd",        
    "cursorHomeSelect",
    {
                 // pad with equal number of /'s before and after text

      "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
      "args": {
        "snippet": "////////////////////////////// $TM_SELECTED_TEXT //////////////////////////////"
      }
    },

    "cursorHomeSelect",
    {
      "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", 
      "args": {
        "name": "Create a Text Block",
      }
    },
    "cursorDown"
  ]
},
```

A snippet (in one of your snippets files):

```
"Create a Text Block": {
  "prefix": "tb",
  "body": [

    "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////", 
    "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.*)(.{57})(\\1).*/$2/g}",
    "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////",    

  ],
  "description": "create a text block"
},
```

And a keybinding (keybindings.json) to trigger the macro.

```
{
  "key": "alt+b",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.createTextBlock" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
```

To explain the macro:

You had 57 /'s on each line without any text, so that is what I used - chose some amount.

Step 1 of the macro: The text is selected and padded at the start and end of the text with lots of /'s.  Must be an equal number of /'s before and after the text for the regex to do its magic - I used about 30 or so.

Step 2: The snippet is inserted.

**The interesting part**.  Keep the **middle 57 characters** of the line containing the text with the regex `(.*)(.{57})(\\1).*`. The `\\1` is a **backreference** to whatever was captured in the first capture group - so capture groups 1 and 3 will be the same length.

And capture group 2 will be our text surrounded by an equal number of /'s (if we added and equal number of /'s before the regex transform which we did).  The `.*` at the very end of the regex is to handle the odd/even number of characters in the text.

[regex101 demo - middle 25 characters](https://regex101.com/r/EE7LT6/1)

[image: demo of create a text block]

And see [How to pad out line to certain length using regex replace and snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869050/how-to-fill-line-to-certain-length-using-regex-replace/56874352#56874352) for a similar question about padding out different lines of text to equal lengths.

Answer (score 0):

That would have to be done via a plugin/extension, not possible natively.

Comment: Ya, I checked the native options. But wasn’t satisfied. Any recommended plugins?

Comment: checkout https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments

I have never used it though. You could also search for other comment plugins and try them out.