# Is it possible to add custom keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to add in custom keyboard shortcuts - rather than just remapping existing key bindings. Is this possible?

The idea is to map a shortcut that will allow me to include an easily identifiable comment header to help index my projects - in this format:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Header
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: [Custom Key Bindings in VSC](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet (which is triggered by typing `cHeader`):

```
"Custom Header": {
  "prefix": ["cHeader"],
  "body": [
    "/*---------------------------------------------------------------",
      "# $1",
    "---------------------------------------------------------------*/"
    ]
}
```

You can make that to whatever length you want.  For more complicated situations, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56874352/836330 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/58722958/836330.

If you want to set a keybinding to that, use this:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+r",            // whatever you want as a keybinding
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "name": "Custom Header"      // name from your snippet above
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: You can also directly embed the snipped in `keybindings.json`, using `"args": {"snippet": "..."}` instead of `"args": {"name": "..."}`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I considered that, but in this case that is extremely ugly since it has to be a one-liner.