# Comment tags like this

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I want to know what is the shortcut for this comment tag like this (VS Code on macOS):

```
<!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                             START SECTION 3 - THE CAMPANIES SECTION  
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
```

Comment: I don't think that vscode has this built-in. You may want to search through extensions, or create a custom snippet.

Comment: Try using Comment Bars Extension in VSC

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58711715/how-to-create-a-comment-block-of-s-around-text-of-different-lengths/58722958#58722958

Answer (score 0):

You can use "control + /" it will comment out any selected line. Also you have to write the design of your comment yourself like if you want something like this "///////////////// START /////////////" then you hav to press ctrl+/ on this line after selecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Select the part of the code you want to comment and follow the methods:

---

Toggling comment blocks as shown below:

Windows: **SHIFT + ALT + A**
Mac: **Shift + Option + A**

```
/* a line of code
   another line of code */
```

---

Another way of commenting is shown below:

- **Commenting**:
  Windows: **Ctrl + K + C**
  Mac: **Command + K + C**
- **Uncommenting**:
  Windows: **Ctrl + K + U**
  Mac: **Command + K + U**

```
// a line of code
// another line of code
```

---

> docs: https://vscode.one/comment-vscode/