# Can I add horizontal rulers in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a way to add horizontal rulers on VS Code when a function exceed 20 lines.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Do you mean like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869050/how-to-pad-out-line-to-certain-length-using-regex-replace-and-snippets/56874352#56874352 or do you want it inserted automatically?  In which case, you will need an extension.

Comment: Or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stackbreak.comment-divider?

Comment: Not really, i'm searching for a way to make like the "editor.rulers" parameter but horitontally when a function exceed 20 lines.

Comment: Great tipp @Mark, the extension works like a charm: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stackbreak.comment-divider